# How to redirect Wishlist output from popup to website url?

Tags: magento2, popup

In category listing page I am using quick view. In Quick View, product detail page is displayed in popup. In that popup I am displaying wishlist also.

Wishlist functionality is working fine but its output is getting redirected to popup url.

For Quick View I have referred link -

```
 https://www.weltpixel.com/advance-product-quick-view.html
```

Wishlist output is getting redirected to popup instead of website url.

```
 <a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>Add to Wishlist</span></a>
```

Comment: You want to redirect on wishlist page or current page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - I want to redirect wishlist output to website url

Comment: Can you explain this is detail, wishlist already available in to website.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
app/code/WeltPixel/Quickview/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

---

Add this code in your file

```
<script>
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
            $(function(){
                $('.action.towishlist').on('click',function(event){
                    var  params, action;

                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    params = $(event.currentTarget).data('post');
                    action = params.action;
                    action += 'product/'+ params.data.product+'/';
                    if (params.data.uenc) {
                        action += 'uenc/' + params.data.uenc;
                    }
                    var FormKey = "<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey(); ?>";
                    action += '/form_key/'+FormKey;
                    if(window.top.location != window.self.location)
                     {
                        top.window.location.href = action;

                     }
                 });             
            });
        });
    </script>
```